# Mathematics courses in computer science

Tags: mathematics, computer-science

What are some typical mathematics courses in an undergraduate mathematics (pure and applied) curriculum that are highly translational to computer science?

Comment: What do you mean by translational?

Comment: @usul Courses in mathematics that are often heavily used in computer science.

Comment: Undergrad-level courses? Pretty much all of them, depending on the sub-area of CS...

Comment: @MarcGlisse What sub-area of CS would be served by Galois theory? Or algebraic or analytic number theory? How about algebraic or differential geometry? I'd dare say that beyond the most elementary introductory courses in a first semester, there are very few courses in a typical mathematics undergraduate programme that are of any use in CS.

Comment: Regarding [CS and Galois theory...](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_12/papers/juan.pdf)

Comment: Sigh another clearly off topic question getting a pass because it’s about math/CS

Comment: @LeeMosher There is no [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Modern_approach_by_field_theory) in the document you link. It just happens to refer to finite fields as 'Galois fields', and does some elementary arithmetic in them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Theoretical computer science rests on quite a large body of mathematical work that goes quite deeply into foundational territory.  Here are some mathematical subjects that are fundamental to a good understanding of theoretical computer science:

- **Logic and set theory:** This is a foundational area in mathematics but it is also a core subject for understanding the mathematics of computer science.  Typical coverage of courses in this field would include propositional logic, predicate logic, modal logic (perhaps), sets, set operations and cardinality, and functions.   Advance courses might also cover axiomatic set theory and delve more deeply into the foundations of mathematics, though these are not absoutely necessary.
- **Discrete Mathematics:** This is a field that covers the study of mathematical structures that are discrete (i.e., coming from finite or countable sets).  Typical coverage of courses in this field could include sequences and series, discrete sets and functions, combinatorics, graph theory, and algorithms.  Though not always covered in computer science contexts, it might also be useful to cover discrete calculus and discrete optimisation.
- **Automata theory:** This field examines the mathematical description and study of "abstract machines" including finite-state machines, pushdown automata, Turing machines and other variants of abstract machines.  It is closely related to the theory of formal languages and the latter can also be included in the field if needed.  This field falls directly in the area of theoretical computer science and is used mostly for computing and linguistics.
- **Complexity theory:** This field examines the computational complexity of problems and algorithms.  Typical coverage of courses in this field would include asymptotic complexity measures (e.g., big-o, little-o notation), evaluation of complexity classes for the time and space needed for computations, and hierarchies of complexity classes.  This field ties in with automata theory because complexity is sometimes evaluated by looking at whether particular problems can be computed with different types of abstract machines.

These are the main areas that I would consider to be directly within the scope of theoretical computer science.  However, it is also useful for theoretical computer scientists to have a broader understanding of other areas of mathematics, including linear algebra, calculus, real analysis, complex analysis, probability, statistics, optimisation, etc.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the post. Really what I was looking for.

Comment: I also want to ask, in what context is complex analysis applied in computer science?

Comment: I teach in an applied curriculum, and we cover areas 1, 2 and 4, but not 3. Areas 1 and 2 are "translational" in the sense that you apply its concepts already writing easy code. Area 4 comes later in the curriculum and requires a solid understanding of 1 & 2. Students who dodge those, struggle a lot with area 4.

Comment: While the OP seems happy with your answer, I don't think _mathematics_ students typically study automata or complexity theory.  Even logic and set theory is probably not really studied by most math students.  I only saw things like predicate logic, complexity theory and automata in CS courses in undergrad, not Math courses (I was a dual-major).

Comment: @Kimball: Yes, that's true.  Students would probably have to seek out courses on automata/complexity rather than having them in standard curriculum.  I'm more concerned here with giving the student good suggestions for areas of study, rather than worrying too much about standard curricula.  I am also premising this answer on the idea that students have some reasonable latitude to search out courses; possibly even related courses from other faculties.

Comment: You mentioned real and complex analysis in your last sentence. I question their applicability to computer science, but they were by far the most nutritious brain food I had at university. A warning to those in the audience who are choosing math courses to take: many will find these courses extremely difficult.

Comment: The main reason I mention complex analysis as an applicable field is because it is useful for understanding various things that crop up in computer science.  Even something as basic as a proper understaning of polynomials requires complex analysis.  I wouldn't think that a CS person would need much complex analysis, but absence of basic knowledge would be a hindrance.

Answer (score 9):

There are several. Probably the most useful are a course in formal logic and a course in discrete (finite) math. Statistics is useful for lots of things also. Statistics usually (and should) requires Calculus and maybe discrete math.

Beyond that, the "mathematical way of thinking" is useful for anyone in CS. Analysis of problems and synthesis of solutions appear in both fields in important ways. Likewise the precision required in both fields is quite similar.

---

Note: This isn't intended to be a comprehensive list. But, as a PhD mathematician and a professor of CS, these are the ones I've found most relevant in general. Other courses may be required for some specialties, of course.

Comment: Calculus, Linear Algebra, Real Analysis are prereqs for Machine Learning, Data Analysis and even Complexity Theory...

Comment: Calculus and linear algebra are also prerequisites for 2D and 3D graphics, as well as physical simulations

Comment: Also abstract algebra - very useful in cryptography but also helps underpin more advanced linear algebra.

Comment: Nice for you to share this perspective.

Comment: @whoisit: May I add probability and statistics? To be honest, while calculus and analysis is important if you want to *create* a new ML algorithm, you won't be using it if you "just" want to *apply* ML. In contrast, probability and statistics (and linear algebra) are *hugely* important in *both* creating and applying. I am working in ML, and the utter inability of many CS experts wrap their heads around probability and stats baffles me. (And makes for many very frustrating questions at CrossValidated.)

Answer (score 5):

[ABET's Computing Accreditation Commission](https://www.abet.org/accreditation/accreditation-criteria/criteria-for-accrediting-computing-programs-2023-2024/) says, for programs named Computer Science:

> At least 15 semester credit hours (or equivalent) that must include
> discrete mathematics and must have mathematical rigor at least
> equivalent to introductory calculus. The additional mathematics might
> include course work in areas such as calculus, linear algebra,
> numerical methods, probability, statistics, or number theory.

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer.

Comment: @Abdulrahman You're welcome! The other answers are more comprehensive, but I thought this was a relevant piece of information.